# magento error of creating product

Tags: php, magento, soap

i got error of my magento api than i creating the product:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Access denied. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/soap.php:210 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/soap.php(210): SoapClient->__call('call', Array) #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/soap.php(210): SoapClient->call('2017c612ade741b...', 'product_attribu...') #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/soap.php(90): Client->_APIgetAttributeSets() #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/soap.php(269): Client->APIcreateNewProduct(Array) #4 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/soap.php on line 210
```

this is my method:

```
public function APIcreateNewProduct( $newProductData ) {

    $error = array();

    if( empty( $newProductData ) ) {
        $error[] = 'Empty product data';
    }

    if( empty( $error ) ) {

        $token = $this->_getToken();
        $client = $this->_getClient();
//90 line
        $set = $this->_APIgetAttributeSets();

        $productId = $client->call($token, self::CREATE_PRODUCT, array('simple', $set['set_id'], rand().'sku_of_product', $newProductData));
        return $productId;

    } else {
        return $this->_apiJsonResult( $error );
    }

}
```

and its _APIgetAttributeSets():

```
private function _APIgetAttributeSets() {

    $token = $this->_getToken();
    $client = $this->_getClient();
//210 LINE
    $attributeSets = $client->call($token, self::PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_LIST);
    $set = current($attributeSets);

    return $set;
}
```

Login and retrieving the product list are fine.

where is my mistake with creating? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check this webservice user has given create and delete right in backend. if not then give right for create product and check it.